# Error of start of the demon of Namenode

Tags: java, linux, unix, hadoop, mapreduce

My purpose - to launch the demon of namenode. It is necessary for me to work with file system of hdfs, to copy there files from local file system, to create folders in hdfs, and it requires start of the demon of namenode on the port specified in the configuration /conf/core-site.xml file.
I launched a script

```
./hadoop namenode
```

and I received as a result the following messages

```
2013-02-17 12:29:37,493 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = one/192.168.1.8
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1243785; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Tue Feb 14 08:15:38 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-02-17 12:29:38,325 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-02-17 12:29:38,400 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:38,427 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-02-17 12:29:38,427 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-02-17 12:29:39,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:39,542 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-02-17 12:29:39,633 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:39,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:39,704 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2013-02-17 12:29:39,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2013-02-17 12:29:39,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2013-02-17 12:29:39,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2013-02-17 12:29:42,718 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hadoop
2013-02-17 12:29:42,737 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-02-17 12:29:42,738 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-02-17 12:29:42,937 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-02-17 12:29:42,940 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-02-17 12:29:45,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-02-17 12:29:46,229 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-02-17 12:29:46,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 1
2013-02-17 12:29:47,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0
2013-02-17 12:29:47,134 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-02-17 12:29:47,134 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Edits file /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-02-17 12:29:47,163 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-02-17 12:29:47,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-02-17 12:29:47,479 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups
2013-02-17 12:29:47,480 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 6294 msecs
2013-02-17 12:29:47,919 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Total number of blocks = 0
2013-02-17 12:29:47,919 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of invalid blocks = 0
2013-02-17 12:29:47,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0
2013-02-17 12:29:47,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0
2013-02-17 12:29:47,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode termination scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 430 msec
2013-02-17 12:29:47,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Leaving safe mode after 6 secs.
2013-02-17 12:29:47,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes
2013-02-17 12:29:47,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks
2013-02-17 12:29:48,198 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2013-02-17 12:29:48,279 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 129 msec
2013-02-17 12:29:48,279 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 129 msec processing time, 129 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-02-17 12:29:48,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
2013-02-17 12:29:48,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-02-17 12:29:48,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:48,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-02-17 12:29:48,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort2000 registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:48,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort2000 registered.
2013-02-17 12:29:48,865 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: one/192.168.1.8:2000
2013-02-17 12:30:23,264 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-02-17 12:30:25,326 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-02-17 12:30:25,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
2013-02-17 12:30:25,997 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
2013-02-17 12:30:26,269 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop cause:java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2013-02-17 12:30:26,442 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicationMonitor thread received InterruptedException.java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2013-02-17 12:30:26,445 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0 
2013-02-17 12:30:26,446 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 2000
2013-02-17 12:30:26,446 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down
2013-02-17 12:30:26,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager: Interrupted Monitor
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager$Monitor.run(DecommissionManager.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-02-17 12:30:26,761 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:581)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:353)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:353)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)

2013-02-17 12:30:26,784 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at one/192.168.1.8
************************************************************/
```

Help to launch the demon of namenode for further start of hadoop of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2013-02-17 12:30:26,761 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Looks like you already have a process running on the same port at the one the Name Node binds to. Probably means you already have an instance of the name node process running.

You should be able to use either the `jps -v` command to list the running java processes for the current user, or `ps aww | grep java` to list all running java processes.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your IP address is mapped correctly in /etc/hosts file. Check using ifconfig and map to the correct DNS name. This error is thrown if the mapping is not correct also.