# Hangup in case of start of the demon of Namenode

Tags: java, linux, unix, hadoop, mapreduce

I changed port with 9000 on 5000 in the configuration core-site.xml file and launched a script

```
./hadoop namenode
```

and as a result I received the following messages (I give only part that saw from the screen as in a log file didn't register)

```
13/02/17 22:42:39 INFO http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled=false
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070

13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO namenode.Namenode: Web-server up at: 0.0.0.0:50070
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 5000: starting
```

On it process stopped and already some hours hang. Such already was last time and I removed its clicking of Ctrl+Z, but as a result in case of next run of the demon of Namenode with the help

```
./hadoop namenode
```

I received the messages provided on [Error of start of the demon of Namenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926077/error-of-start-of-the-demon-of-namenode/14926140#14926140) . What shall I do: to stop process (but then reset of the virtual machine is necessary and port change is possible, and it is in the long term unclear - whether will hang up next time) or to wait? But in any case meanwhile a situation desperate (concerning Namenode start) therefore I hope that alternative options will be offered.

Answer (score 1):

few things how to better understand/analyze your error:

1. `./hadoop namenode  &> out` from here you can read the full error stack trace (both STDIN as well as STDOUT are redirected into `out` file)
2. Pressing Ctrl-Z you put the process into background (you are not killing them). Therefore you got "port already in use" error. You need to kill currently running application and start again)
3. before running the command make sure whether the port is not already in use